# Notification when Wifi disconnect

Tags: 12.04, command-line, wireless, sound, notification

I run a script in terminal but sometimes wifi disconnects and script stops working. I am mostly away from the laptop, so is there a way to make me notify with sound when wifi disconnect?

> In addition to **Patrick Trentin**'s solution. If you want this kind
>   of script, you can try the python version of it. Both work well. Here:
>
> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1490776

Comment: What is the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very **simple** script for achieving such a thing could be the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

PERIOD=10       # s.
WARNING_TEXT="Warning: the connection to SKYNET was lost."
LANGUAGE="en"
ICON="notification-network-wireless-disconnected"

# conn_monitor.sh:
# polls the connection state after PERIOD seconds, and reads aloud a warning message
# in case there is no connection
#
# dependencies:
# - sudo apt-get install espeak binutils libmad libnotify-bin
# NOTES:
# - nm-tool has been replaced by nmcli in newer versions of ubuntu (>= 15.04),
#   see the output of `nmcli dev` to adapt this script to your needs.

function conn_monitor() {
    while true :
    do
        sleep ${PERIOD}
        mem_data=$(nm-tool | grep "State: connected")

        if [[ -z "${mem_data}" ]]; then
            notify-send "${WARNING_TEXT}" -i ${ICON} -u critical
            paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/suspend-error.oga
            espeak -a 200 -v ${LANGUAGE} "${WARNING_TEXT}"
        fi
    done
};

if [[ "$BASH_SOURCE" == "$0" ]]; then
    conn_monitor $@
else
    export -f conn_monitor
fi
```

Then you can add a file named `conn_monitor.desktop` in `~/.config/autostart` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=..path..to..your..script..
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Conn Monitor
Comment=
```

in which you correctly set the path to your script location.

---

I tested the script on **ubuntu 14.04**.

Comment: thank you, it seems perfect, I guess it won't be a problem in 12.04 non-pae cpu. But should I run it in terminal too or show it as a system file? As I said It is non-pae so it is very old laptop, memory can be a issue, I have already been running 2 python web scripts all day long.

Comment: This script shouldn't increase the memory consumption in any significant manner, it will however consume cpu-time. You can increase the period to reduce such a consumption, with the drawback of receiving notifications with a lower frequency.  As it is, it doesn't consume more than 1%, at least on my machine. If you don't plan to restart the machine any-time soon, you can launch it with `nohup conn_monitor.sh &` and forget about it. Be sure to have the audio turned on, though.